# Profile Language Syntax Highlighting C# Extension for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, plugins, add-in

I have an add-in for Visual Studio for Java like profile files. A sample file can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

The problem occurs when the **\** character is inserted on a specific line. When backwards slash is used, the next line is interpreted as a value (or as a key, or as a key and a value). A simple example is:

```
1. part1_key\
2. part2_key\
3. part3_key = value

4. key = part1_value\
5.       part2_value
```

The syntax highlighter works when the file is loaded, but when a line is modified, only *that* line is evaluated and highlighted. So, when the **\** is inserted on line 4 for example, the line 4 is highlighted, but the line 5 is **not** updated. The line 5 is updated only when it's modified (add or remove a character, or a space).

I've created a **ITaggerProvider** which creates an **ITagger** whose type is *Key*, *Value* or *Comment*. The *ITagger* class is as follows:

```
internal sealed class PropertiesTokenTagger : ITagger<PropertiesTokenTag> {
        private readonly Regex keyValuePattern = new Regex(@"(?<!^\s*|\\)([ \t]*[=:][ \t]*|[ \t]+)");
        private readonly Regex separatorPattern = new Regex(@"^([=:]|[ \t]+)");
        private readonly Regex commentPattern = new Regex(@"^\s*[#!]");
        private readonly Regex escapedLineEndPattern = new Regex(@"\\$");

        public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged {
            add { }
            remove { }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans) {
            // sadly `spans` gets one line at a time, so previouslyEscapedValue will not get the chance to be used
            foreach (var curSpan in spans) {
                var containingLine = curSpan.Start.GetContainingLine();
                var lineStartLoc = containingLine.Start.Position;
                var lineText = containingLine.GetText();
                var previousIsNotComment = false;

                var previousLine = curSpan.Snapshot.Lines.LastOrDefault(l => l.End <= curSpan.Start);
                if (previousLine != null && escapedLineEndPattern.IsMatch(previousLine.GetText())) {
                    var previousToken = GetTags(new NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection(previousLine.Extent)).ToList();

                    if (previousToken.Count > 0) {
                        var propertiesTokenTypes = previousToken.Last().Tag.Type;
                        if (propertiesTokenTypes == PropertiesValue) {
                            var valueSpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc, lineText.Length));
                            yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(valueSpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesValue));
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (propertiesTokenTypes == PropertiesKey && separatorPattern.IsMatch(lineText)) {
                            var valueSpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc, lineText.Length));
                            yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(valueSpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesValue));
                            continue;
                        }

                        previousIsNotComment = propertiesTokenTypes != PropertiesComment;
                    }
                }

                if (commentPattern.IsMatch(lineText) && !previousIsNotComment) {
                    var commentSpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc, lineText.Length));
                    yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(commentSpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesComment));
                    continue;
                }

                if (keyValuePattern.IsMatch(lineText)) {
                    var splitPosition = keyValuePattern.Split(lineText)[0].Length;
                    var keySpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc, splitPosition));
                    yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(keySpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesKey));
                    var valueSpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc + splitPosition + 1, lineText.Length - splitPosition - 1));
                    yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(valueSpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesValue));
                } else {
                    var keySpan = new SnapshotSpan(curSpan.Snapshot, new Span(lineStartLoc, lineText.Length));
                    yield return new TagSpan<PropertiesTokenTag>(keySpan, new PropertiesTokenTag(PropertiesKey));
                }
            }
        }
```

---

From what I see, the problem is the fact that **GetTags** method is called from an external source, and I cannot call manually this method in order to update other lines. This method return a *List* of **TagSpans** which *intersects* the *NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection* parameter, so if I try to return a tag for another line other than current line, that tag won't be processed.

LE: I've done it, the solution was to raise the TagsChanged event from outside GetTags method, and also in aggregator from *ITagger*.